# Context is lost when reassigning Transaction.Current in async/await code

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, transactionscope, rebus

When reassigning `Transaction.Current`, I seem to lose the original `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` behavior of my `TransactionScope`. The code after the second `await` loses it's `Transaction.Current` value.

Sample code (Linqpad):

```
async Task Main()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.Dump("before await");
    var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    var transaction = Transaction.Current;

    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.Dump("after first await");
    Transaction.Current = transaction;
    Transaction.Current.Dump(); // not null

    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.Dump("after second await");
    Transaction.Current.Dump(); // is null :/
}
```

I [know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.current?view=netframework-4.8) I should be using a `using` statement on `TransactionScope` rather than reassigning  the ambient transaction, however because of reasons, it's not possible to do that. I'm curious about the reason of the behavior of the snippet above and wonder if there are ways to keep the original `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` behavior.

Comment: Where are you running that code? I tried LINQPad and, if I don't set `Transaction.Current` I allways get the same transaction.

Comment: Looks like the implementation of the setter for `Transaction.Current` always uses TLS context, never async-compatbile context. The implementation of the `TransactionScope` constructor (specifically, `PushScope`) does set either one. Looks like you'll have to open a bug report.

Comment: The associated bug report in dotnet/corefx can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37402).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by wrapping the `Transaction` object in another `TransactionScope` with `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` enabled:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    var transaction = Transaction.Current;

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Transaction.Current = transaction;
    Debug.Assert(Transaction.Current != null); // not null

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Debug.Assert(Transaction.Current == null); // is null :/

    using (var innerScope = new TransactionScope(transaction, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        // Transaction.Current state is kept across async continuations
        Debug.Assert(Transaction.Current != null); // not null
        await Task.Delay(10);
        Debug.Assert(Transaction.Current != null); // not null
        innerScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! And you've submitted your fix in the form of a pull request, which I've accepted and published as Rebus.TransactionScopes 5.0.0-b2 – thanks! 